# JavaFX Slider: Track length? Tick Label Color?

Tags: java, css, javafx, slider, javafx-8

```
.slider .track {
    -fx-pref-width: 300px;
}

.slider .axis-tick-label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

My feeble attempts of writing CSS styles for the slider both don't work. I'm 100% sure my syntax is off. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by setting the `-fx-pref-width` attribute of `slider` and setting the `-fx-tick-label-fill` attribute of `.slider .axis`:

```
.slider { -fx-pref-width: 300px; }
.slider .axis { -fx-tick-label-fill: white; }
```

---

**Note:** For vertical `Slider`, to affect the length of the track, you have to use the `-fx-pref-height` attribute:

```
.slider:vertical { -fx-pref-height:300px; }
```